# Is comma (,) operator or separator in Java?

Tags: java, operators

Well, to be honest, this confuses me a lot. Some books say that comma is not an operator in Java, just a separator. Other say it's both,  an operator as well as a separator. What's true?

Comment: For chaining expressions it's an operator, otherwise a separator for arguments, etc

Comment: Seems to be a good question. Can you give us your book reference ? (mainly by curiosity)

Comment: @technico Java: The complete Reference 9th edition. Herb Schildt. This book says, in Java , comma is just a separator. Thinking in Java says it's both.

Comment: I uh... whew. I don't think anyone thought of it as an operator/separator distinction, but just more or less white noise for arranging the language/grammar accordingly. It's kind of hard to answer this without just saying "it's there because it is". I didn't find anything in the JLS other than that a comma is simply used. I believe the book is correct in saying it's just a separator, defining it as an operator doesn't sit right with me as it doesn't inherently perform a specific operation.

Comment: @Rogue but in some places, comma acts identical to C++'s comma operator.

Comment: when in doubt, the JLS has an overly specific explanation for it.

Comment: Why/when would a comma be an operator?

Comment: @shmosel C considers the comma as an operator in expression lists.

Comment: @EJP But commas don't have that meaning in Java.

Comment: (And at least in JLS for  SE7 the JLS explicitly states in 15.27 that Java doesn't have a comma operator. At least one blog post refers to it as an operator for expression lists, like in for loop initializers, but that seems a semantic distinction rather than a language definition over.)

Comment: @DaveNewton `,` is not an operator in Java, period, and if a blog post thinks it's an operator, then the blogger is simply confusing it with C/C++.  I don't think it's a semantic distinction--I think it's just an error on the blogger's part.

Comment: @ajb That's what I said.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`,` is not an operator in Java, as it is in C.  In C, you can use the `,` operator between two expressions to cause it to evaluate both and return the second.  You can't do that in Java.

You can still do this:

```
for (i = 1, j = 2; i < max; i++, j++) {
}
```

In C, the three parts of the `for` header are all single expressions, and it uses the fact that `,` is an operator to allow statements like the above--`i=1, j=2` is one expression, and `i++, j++` is one expression.  In Java, the syntax of `for` has to allow for expression lists specifically, so `i=1, j=2` is two expressions, as is `i++, j++`.

Answer (score 3):

Found it, Java classes commas as a separator. JLS [§3.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.11)

> Nine ASCII characters are the separators (punctuators).

```
Separator: one of
(    )    {    }    [    ]    ;    ,    .
```

Update for Java 8:

> Twelve tokens, formed from ASCII characters, are the separators (punctuators).

```
Separator: one of
(   )   {   }   [   ]   ;   ,   .   ...   @   ::
```

Answer (score 1):

For operators in Java, see:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

And here the operators are listed according to precedence order:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

So the comma (<kbd>,</kbd>), isn't an operator, and indeed is a separator as pointed out in the other answer.